# IllegalArgumentException or NullPointerException for a null parameter?

Tags: java, exception, null, nullpointerexception, illegalargumentexception

I have a simple setter method for a property and `null` is not appropriate for this particular property. I have always been torn in this situation: should I throw an [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html), or a [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)? From the javadocs, both seem appropriate. Is there some kind of an understood standard?  Or is this just one of those things that you should do whatever you prefer and both are really correct?

Answer (score 315, accepted):

It seems like an `IllegalArgumentException` is called for if you don't want `null` to be an allowed value, and the `NullPointerException` would be thrown if you were trying to *use* a variable that turns out to be `null`.

Comment: The following answers to this question make persuasive arguments that NullPointerException is the correct exception: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8160/372926 ; http://stackoverflow.com/a/8196334/372926 ; and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6358/372926.

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException` is in contradiction with Java's [Objects.requireNonNull(T)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-) and Guava's [Preconditions.checkNotNull(T)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull-T-) which throws a `NullPointerException`. However, **the right answer is definitelly** `IllegalArgumentException` as explained in [Jason Cohen's excelent answer and it's comment section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47710/4413257).

Answer (score 446):

You should be using `IllegalArgumentException` (IAE), not `NullPointerException` (NPE) for the following reasons:

First, the [NPE JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) explicitly lists the cases where NPE is appropriate.  Notice that all of them are thrown *by the runtime* when `null` is used inappropriately.  In contrast, the [IAE JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) couldn't be more clear: "Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument."  Yup, that's you!

Second, when you see an NPE in a stack trace, what do you assume?  Probably that someone dereferenced a `null`.  When you see IAE, you assume the caller of the method at the top of the stack passed in an illegal value.  Again, the latter assumption is true, the former is misleading.

Third, since IAE is clearly designed for validating parameters, you have to assume it as the default choice of exception, so why would you choose NPE instead?  Certainly not for different behavior -- do you really expect calling code to catch NPE's separately from IAE and do something different as a result?  Are you trying to communicate a more specific error message?  But you can do that in the exception message text anyway, as you should for all other incorrect parameters.

Fourth, all other incorrect parameter data will be IAE, so why not be consistent?  Why is it that an illegal `null` is so special that it deserves a separate exception from all other types of illegal arguments?

Finally, I accept the argument given by other answers that parts of the Java API use NPE in this manner.  However, the Java API is inconsistent with everything from exception types to naming conventions, so I think just blindly copying (your favorite part of) the Java API isn't a good enough argument to trump these other considerations.

Comment: Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 60: "Arguably, all erroneous method invocations boil down to an illegal argument or illegal state, but other exceptions are standardly used for certain kinds of illegal arguments and states. If a caller passes null in some parameter for which null values are prohibited, convention dictates that NullPointerException be thrown rather than IllegalArgumentException. Similarly, if a caller passes an out-of-range value in a parameter representing an index into a sequence, IndexOutOfBoundsException should be thrown rather than IllegalArgumentException."

Comment: The JavaDoc for NPE also states the following: "Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of the null object." This one could be more clear :(

Comment: Unfortunately, the validation methods `Validate.notNull` (commons lang) and `Preconditions.checkNotNull` (guava) both throw NPE :-(

Comment: Although Guava also has Preconditions.checkArgument() throws IllegalArgumentException ...

Comment: "When you see IAE, you assume the caller of the method at the top of the stack passed in an illegal value. Again, the latter assumption is true, the former is misleading." -- It's not at all misleading, quite the contrary. Had you not explicitly checked for a null argument value, you would have gotten an NPE when you used it. The check is just to make the details of the logic error explicit. There is no *logical* difference between a program that throws an NPE upon derefing null and a program that throws an exception in lieu of derefing null. The exception message should make the cause clear.

Comment: "Although Guava also has Preconditions.checkArgument() throws IllegalArgumentException" -- yes, so? That takes a boolean condition; it isn't for use with null arguments.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, from the Guava docs:

"We realize there are many valid arguments in favor of throwing IAE on a null argument. In fact, if we had a time machine to go back >15 years, we might even try to push things in that direction. However, we have decided to stick with the JDK and Effective Java preference of NullPointerException. If you're steadfast in your belief that IAE is right, you still have `checkArgument(arg != null)`, just without the convenience of it returning arg, or you can create a local utility to your project."

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IdeaGraveyard

Comment: I second this answer. I guess "Wisdom, not rules" (http://javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=259) applies here.

Comment: I am using IllegalArgumentException if an argument is given, yet "illegal" in terms of being wrong (as it is unknown to my application - possibly misspelled). I am uncertain about what to throw if no argument is passed - since my application expects at least two arguments...

Comment: NPE: "Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of the null object."
IAE: "Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument."

Comment: If you want to be specific, check and throw IAE, if not just let the NPE happen naturally. It is a matter of choice to be explicit (IAE) or implicit (NPE) both are fine, as long as you never throw an NPE explicitly in code :)

Comment: Also from test-case perspective, IAE is more suitable, since NPE can be any line of code with "null.callMethod()", while IAE immediatelly identifies invalid argument scenario.

Comment: aaaand there is [java.util.Objects.requireNonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)), fromJava 7 till now, just to simplify throwing NPE ;-)
I know there are also Guava's Preconditions and apache commons' Validate, but simply looking at the latter's [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html#notNull-T-): it is deprecated, and it tells that's better to use Objects.requireNonNull.

Answer (score 171):

The standard is to throw the `NullPointerException`. The generally infallible "Effective Java" discusses this briefly in Item 42 (first edition), Item 60 (second edition), or Item 72 (third edition) "Favor the use of standard exceptions":

> "Arguably, all erroneous method
>   invocations boil down to an illegal
>   argument or illegal state, but other
>   exceptions are standardly used for
>   certain kinds of illegal arguments and
>   states. If a caller passes null in
>   some parameter for which null values
>   are prohibited, convention dictates
>   that NullPointerException be thrown
>   rather than IllegalArgumentException."

Comment: I strongly disagree. NullPointerExceptions should only be thrown if the JVM accidentially follows a null reference.   That is the difference that helps you when called in to look at code at 3 in the morning.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with the standard (I could actually go either way on the issue), but that IS what the standard usage throughout the JDK is, hence Effective Java making the case for it. I think this is a case of choosing whether or not to follow the standard, or do the thing you feel is right. Unless you have a very good reason (and this certainly may qualify), it's best to follow standard practice.

Comment: Actually, the NullPointerException is supposed to be thrown for "illegal uses of the null reference". Indeed, encapsulation means you should *know* whether it was caused by the JVM  actually dereferencing a bad pointer or the app just rejecting it.

Comment: Agree with Thorbjorn, do yourself a favor and avoid debugging hell.

Comment: The exception trace shows the point of the exception, so if the difference in the type of the exception causes hell for you or is "the difference that helps you", you are doing something very wrong.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the stack trace will point you at the exact same spot anyway? certainly doesn't make *that* much of a difference

Comment: @djechlin it allows you or others to triage the problem early without having to wake a programmer to look at the precise source first.

Comment: @JimBalter If nullpointerexceptions are never thrown by _your_ code but only by the JVM when resolving a `.` or an array index, you can immediately say whether this is bad data caught by your code, or this is unforeseen data resulting in a code malfunction, without having to look at the source first.  In a production failure where downtime may be expensive this may allow the initial investigator to react correctly without having to wake up a vendor programmer first.

Comment: Fantasies and sophistry. Just below, MB writes "Note that the arguments about hard debugging are bogus because you can of course provide a message to NullPointerException saying what was null and why it shouldn't be null. Just like with IllegalArgumentException."

Comment: Also, these points were covered by Christopher Smith , among others, 4 1/2 years ago ... continuing to bring up bogus points is trolling.

Comment: As the original answerer here, let me say it just doesn't matter that much. It certainly doesn't warrant 6 years of conversation. Pick one, whichever you like, and be consistent. The standard, as I pointed out, is NPE. If you prefer IAE for whatever reasons, go for it. Just be consistent.

Comment: it is this quote that brought me here, as i disagree... i guess i won't really find an answer here. i will keep on throwing IAEs rather than NPEs, though I have seen NPE thrown from the java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(Driver) method, if Driver is null, NPE is thrown explicitly. I wondered WHY.

Comment: NullPointerException could be thrown not only by null parameters, but also by null variables inside the method.

Answer (score 153):

I was all in favour of throwing `IllegalArgumentException` for null parameters, until today, when I noticed the `java.util.Objects.requireNonNull` method in Java 7.  With that method, instead of doing:

```
if (param == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("param cannot be null.");
}
```

you can do:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(param);
```

and it will throw a `NullPointerException` if the parameter you pass it is `null`.

Given that that method is right bang in the middle of `java.util` I take its existence to be a pretty strong indication that throwing `NullPointerException` is "the Java way of doing things".

I think I'm decided at any rate.

Note that the arguments about hard debugging are bogus because you can of course provide a message to `NullPointerException` saying what was null and why it shouldn't be null.  Just like with `IllegalArgumentException`.

One added advantage of `NullPointerException` is that, in highly performance critical code, you could dispense with an explicit check for null (and a `NullPointerException` with a friendly error message), and just rely on the `NullPointerException` you'll get automatically when you call a method on the null parameter.  Provided you call a method quickly (i.e. fail fast), then you have essentially the same effect, just not quite as user friendly for the developer.  Most times it's probably better to check explicitly and throw with a useful message to indicate which parameter was null, but it's nice to [have the option of changing that](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22275/Unify-exceptions-from-null-checks#focus=Comments-27-3243198.0-0) if performance dictates without breaking the published contract of the method/constructor.

Comment: Guava `Preconditions.checkNotNull(arg)` also throws NPE.

Comment: This isn't really adding more weight to NullPointerException for illegal null ARGUMENTS. Both the JDK requireNonNull() and Guava checkNotNull() can be called anywhere in the code, with any object. You could call them inside a loop for example. requireNotNull() and checkNotNull() could not possibly assume to be invoked with some method arguments and throw IllegalArgumentException. Note that Guava also has Preconditions.checkArgument() which does throw IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: A fair point by Bogdan, though I suspect the typical (and generally intended) use of requireNonNull is for argument checking.  If you needed to check that something wasn't null in a loop I'd have thought an assertion would be the typical way.

Comment: I think the JavaDoc of Object.requireNonNull() adds weight to the argument: "This method is designed primarily for doing parameter validation in methods and constructors"

Comment: Keep in mind that the performance argument in favor of implicit null checks is often invalid. The JIT is able to recognize user null checks and elide the following implied null check, and/or use the same set of optimizations on either type of null check. See [this wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PerformanceTechniques) for more info, in particular: _User-written null checks are in most cases functionally identical to those inserted by the JVM._ Of course, if you are doing something fancier in your null like custom messages, this optimization  may not apply.

Answer (score 75):

I tend to follow the design of JDK libraries, especially Collections and Concurrency (Joshua Bloch, Doug Lea, those guys know how to design solid APIs). Anyway, many APIs in the JDK pro-actively throws `NullPointerException`.

For example, the Javadoc for `Map.containsKey` states:

> @throws NullPointerException if the key is null and this map
>     does not permit null keys (optional).

It's perfectly valid to throw your own NPE. The convention is to include the parameter name which was null in the message of the exception.

The pattern goes:

```
public void someMethod(Object mustNotBeNull) {  
    if (mustNotBeNull == null) {  
        throw new NullPointerException("mustNotBeNull must not be null");  
    }  
}
```

Whatever you do, don't allow a bad value to get set and throw an exception later when other code attempts to use it. That makes debugging a nightmare. You should always the follow the "fail-fast" principle.

Comment: Food for thought: Maybe the reason that NullPointerException doesn't extend IllegalArgumentException is that the former can occur in cases not involving method arguments.

Comment: @Gili: maybe this problem exists in the first place because Java does not support multiple inheritance. If Java supports MI, you'd be able to throw an exception that inherits from both IllegalArgumentException and NullPointerException.

Comment: The message needs not to include the argument, since it would be always null, giving: "null must not be null", not very useful. :-) Otherwise, I agree, you can make a "rich" NPE, with a meaningful message.

Comment: I have to agree - follow the standard API when in doubt. Not everything in the API is optimal mind you, but still it's maintained and iterated by hundreds of developers, and used by millions of programmers. Now in Java 7 we have another example of the NPE being used in this way; the Objects.requireNonNull(T obj) method - clearly specified for checking that object references are non-null, clearly specified for doing parameter validation in methods/constructors, and clearly specified to throw an NPE if the object is null. End of

Answer (score 49):

Voted up Jason Cohen's argument because it was well presented. Let me dismember it step by step. ;-)

- The [NPE JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) explicitly says, *"other illegal uses of the null object"*. If it was just limited to situations where the runtime encounters a null when it shouldn't, all such cases could be defined far more succinctly.
- Can't help it if you assume the wrong thing, but assuming encapsulation is applied properly, you really shouldn't care or notice whether a null was dereferenced inappropriately vs. whether a method detected an inappropriate null and fired an exception off.
- I'd choose [NPE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) over [IAE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) for multiple reasons

  - It is more specific about the nature of the illegal operation
  - Logic that mistakenly allows nulls tends to be very different from logic that mistakenly allows illegal values. For example, if I'm validating data entered by a user, if I get value that is unacceptable, the source of that error is with the end user of the application. If I get a null, that's programmer error.
  - Invalid values can cause things like stack overflows, out of memory errors, parsing exceptions, etc. Indeed, most errors generally present, at some point, as an invalid value in some method call. For this reason I see IAE as actually the *MOST GENERAL* of all exceptions under RuntimeException.
- Actually, other invalid arguments can result in all kinds of other exceptions. [UnknownHostException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html), [FileNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html), a variety of syntax error exceptions, [IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html), authentication failures, etc., etc.

In general, I feel NPE is much maligned because traditionally has been associated with code that fails to follow the [fail fast principle](http://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf). That, plus the JDK's failure to populate NPE's with a message string really has created a strong negative sentiment that isn't well founded. Indeed, the difference between NPE and IAE from a runtime perspective is strictly the name. From that perspective, the more precise you are with the name, the more clarity you give to the caller.

Comment: The difference between most unchecked exceptions is just the name.

Answer (score 22):

It's a "Holy War" style question. In others words, both alternatives are good, but people will have their preferences which they will defend to the death.

Comment: No, There is just one right answer to this question and that is to use throw IllegalArgument exception when the input to the method is incorrect. Also in dev environment, you can use assertions to check input validity and throw proper exception ;)

Comment: @Mr.Q And I think that `NullPointerException` should be thrown: it's the convention that the JDK uses, and requires for interfaces, it's more specific (just like `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, etc.), etc.

Comment: kekekekkek... :D

Answer (score 18):

If it's a `setter` method and `null` is being passed to it, I think it would make more sense to throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. A `NullPointerException` seems to make more sense in the case where you're attempting to actually use the `null`.

So, if you're using it and it's `null`, `NullPointer`. If it's being passed in and it's `null`, `IllegalArgument`.

Answer (score 10):

Apache Commons Lang has a [NullArgumentException](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang/NullArgumentException.html) that does a number of the things discussed here: it extends IllegalArgumentException and its sole constructor takes the name of the argument which should have been non-null.

While I feel that throwing something like a NullArgumentException or IllegalArgumentException more accurately describes the exceptional circumstances, my colleagues and I have chosen to defer to Bloch's advice on the subject.

Comment: Note they removed it from commons-lang3: http://apache-commons.680414.n4.nabble.com/commons-lang3-NullArgumentException-missing-td4222254.html

Answer (score 8):

Actually, the question of throwing IllegalArgumentException or NullPointerException is in my humble view only a "holy war" for a minority with an incomlete understanding of exception handling in Java. In general, the rules are simple, and as follows:

- argument constraint violations must be indicated as fast as possible (-> fast fail), in order to avoid illegal states which are much harder to debug
- in case of an invalid null pointer for whatever reason, throw NullPointerException
- in case of an illegal array/collection index, throw ArrayIndexOutOfBounds
- in case of a negative array/collection size, throw NegativeArraySizeException
- in case of an illegal argument that is not covered by the above, and for which you don't have another more specific exception type, throw IllegalArgumentException as a wastebasket
- on the other hand, in case of a constraint violation WITHIN A FIELD that could not be avoided by fast fail for some valid reason, catch and rethrow as IllegalStateException or a more specific checked exception. Never let pass the original NullPointerException, ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, etc in this case!

There are at least three very good reasons against the case of mapping all kinds of argument constraint violations to IllegalArgumentException, with the third probably being so severe as to mark the practice bad style:

(1) A programmer cannot a safely assume that all cases of argument constraint violations result in IllegalArgumentException, because the large majority of standard classes use this exception rather as a wastebasket if there is no more specific kind of exception available. Trying to map all cases of argument constraint violations to IllegalArgumentException in your API only leads to programmer frustration using your classes, as the standard libraries mostly follow different rules that violate yours, and most of your API users will use them as well!

(2) Mapping the exceptions actually results in a different kind of anomaly, caused by single inheritance: All Java exceptions are classes, and therefore support single inheritance only. Therefore, there is no way to create an exception that is truly say both a NullPointerException and an IllegalArgumentException, as subclasses can only inherit from one or the other. Throwing an IllegalArgumentException in case of a null argument therefore makes it harder for API users to distinguish between problems whenever a program tries to programmatically correct the problem, for example by feeding default values into a call repeat!

(3) Mapping actually creates the danger of bug masking: In order to map argument constraint violations into IllegalArgumentException, you'll need to code an outer try-catch within every method that has any constrained arguments. However, simply catching RuntimeException in this catch block is out of the question, because that risks mapping documented RuntimeExceptions thrown by libery methods used within yours into IllegalArgumentException, even if they are no caused by argument constraint violations. So you need to be very specific, but even that effort doesn't protect you from the case that you accidentally map an undocumented runtime exception of another API (i.e. a bug) into an IllegalArgumentException of your API. Even the most careful mapping therefore risks masking programming errors of other library makers as argument constraint violations of your method's users, which is simply hillareous behavior!

With the standard practice on the other hand, the rules stay simple, and exception causes stay unmasked and specific. For the method caller, the rules are easy as well:
- if you encounter a documented runtime exception of any kind because you passed an illegal value, either repeat the call with a default (for this specific exceptions are neccessary), or correct your code
- if on the other hand you enccounter a runtime exception that is not documented to happen for a given set of arguments, file a bug report to the method's makers to ensure that either their code or their documentation is fixed.

Answer (score 8):

As a subjective question this should be closed, but as it's still open:

This is part of the internal policy used at my previous place of employment and it worked really well. This is all from memory so I can't remember the exact wording. It's worth noting that they did not use checked exceptions, but that is beyond the scope of the question. The unchecked exceptions they did use fell into 3 main categories.

NullPointerException: Do not throw intentionally. NPEs are to be thrown only by the VM when dereferencing a null reference. All possible effort is to be made to ensure that these are never thrown. @Nullable and @NotNull should be used in conjunction with code analysis tools to find these errors.

IllegalArgumentException: Thrown when an argument to a function does not conform to the public documentation, such that the error can be identified and described in terms of the arguments passed in. The OP's situation would fall into this category.

IllegalStateException: Thrown when a function is called and its arguments are either unexpected at the time they are passed or incompatible with the state of the object the method is a member of.

For example, there were two internal versions of the IndexOutOfBoundsException used in things that had a length. One a sub-class of IllegalStateException, used if the index was larger than the length. The other a subclass of IllegalArgumentException, used if the index was negative. This was because you could add more items to the object and the argument would be valid, while a negative number is never valid.

As I said, this system works really well, and it took someone to explain why the distinction is there: "Depending on the type of error it is quite straightforward for you to figure out what to do. Even if you can't actually figure out what went wrong you can figure out where to catch that error and create additional debugging information."

NullPointerException: Handle the Null case or put in an assertion so that the NPE is not thrown. If you put in an assertion is just one of the other two types. If possible, continue debugging as if the assertion was there in the first place.

IllegalArgumentException: you have something wrong at your call site. If the values being passed in are from another function, find out why you are receiving an incorrect value. If you are passing in one of your arguments propagate the error checks up the call stack until you find the function that is not returning what you expect.

IllegalStateException: You have not called your functions in the correct order. If you are using one of your arguments, check them and throw an IllegalArgumentException describing the issue. You can then propagate the cheeks up against the stack until you find the issue.

Anyway, his point was that you can only copy the IllegalArgumentAssertions up the stack. There is no way for you to propagate the IllegalStateExceptions or NullPointerExceptions up the stack because they had something to do with your function.

Answer (score 7):

Couldn't agree more with what's being said.  Fail early, fail fast.  Pretty good Exception mantra.

The question about which Exception to throw is mostly a matter of personal taste.  In my mind IllegalArgumentException seems more specific than using a NPE since it's telling me that the problem was with an argument I passed to the method and not with a value that may have been generated while performing the method.

My 2 Cents

Answer (score 6):

The accepted practice if to use the *IllegalArgumentException( String message )* to declare a parameter to be invalid and give as much detail as possible... So to say that a parameters was found to be null while exception non-null, you would do something like this:

```
if( variable == null )
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The object 'variable' cannot be null");
```

You have virtually no reason to implicitly use the "NullPointerException". The NullPointerException is an exception thrown by the Java Virtual Machine when you try to execute code on null reference (Like *toString()*).

Answer (score 6):

Throwing an exception that's exclusive to `null` arguments (whether `NullPointerException` or a custom type) makes automated `null` testing more reliable. This automated testing can be done with reflection and a set of default values, as in [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`NullPointerTester`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/testing/NullPointerTester.java). For example, `NullPointerTester` would attempt to call the following method...

```
Foo(String string, List<?> list) {
  checkArgument(string.length() > 0);
  // missing null check for list!
  this.string = string;
  this.list = list;
}
```

...with two lists of arguments: `"", null` and `null, ImmutableList.of()`. It would test that each of these calls throws the expected `NullPointerException`. For this implementation, passing a `null` list does *not* produce `NullPointerException`. It does, however, happen to produce an `IllegalArgumentException` because `NullPointerTester` happens to use a default string of `""`. If `NullPointerTester` expects only `NullPointerException` for `null` values, it catches the bug. If it expects `IllegalArgumentException`, it misses it.

Answer (score 5):

Some collections assume that `null` is rejected using `NullPointerException` rather than `IllegalArgumentException`. For example, if you compare a set containing `null` to a set that rejects `null`, the first set will call `containsAll` on the other and catch its `NullPointerException` -- but not `IllegalArgumentException`. (I'm looking at the implementation of `AbstractSet.equals`.)

You could reasonably argue that using unchecked exceptions in this way is an antipattern, that comparing collections that contain `null` to collections that can't contain `null` is a likely bug that really *should* produce an exception, or that putting `null` in a collection at all is a bad idea. Nevertheless, unless you're willing to say that `equals` should throw an exception in such a case, you're stuck remembering that `NullPointerException` is required in certain circumstances but not in others. ("IAE before NPE except after 'c'...")

Somewhat similarly, build tools may insert null checks *automatically*. Notably, Kotlin's compiler [does this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types) when passing a possibly null value to a Java API. And when a check fails, the result is a `NullPointerException`. So, to give consistent behavior to any Kotlin users and Java users that you have, you'd need to use `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I don't see how the contains throws a NPE depending on an element inside the collection. Only reason a NPE is thrown (afaict) is if the collection itself is null (in which case the NPE is thrown because it tries to access it's iterator). This does however raise the question if null input should be checked for or if it should propagate through until it's tried to access.

Comment: `new TreeSet<>().containsAll(Arrays.asList((Object) null));` throws `NPE` because the `List` contains `null`.

Comment: Ah indeed, TreeSet#contains throws NPE "if the specified element is null and this set uses natural ordering, or its comparator does not permit null elements". Only looked at AbstractSet which does allow null, my bad.
Personally I find it weird it doesn't just return false though, since in that case there can't possibly be a null added.

Answer (score 5):

`NullPointerException` thrown when attempting to access an object with a reference variable whose current value is `null`.

`IllegalArgumentException` thrown when a method receives an argument formatted differently than the method expects.

Answer (score 4):

In general, a developer should **never** throw a NullPointerException. This exception is thrown by the runtime when code attempts to dereference a variable who's value is null. Therefore, if your method wants to explicitly disallow null, as opposed to just happening to have a null value raise a NullPointerException, you should throw an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: JavaDoc on NPE has another opinion: "Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of the null object.". Don't be so categorical

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to single out Null arguments from other illegal arguments, so I derived an exception from IAE named NullArgumentException. Without even needing to read the exception message, I know that a null argument was passed into a method and by reading the message, I find out which argument was null. I still catch the NullArgumentException with an IAE handler, but in my logs is where I can see the difference quickly.

Comment: I have adopted the "throw new IllegalArgumentException("foo == null")" approach.  You need to log the variable name anyway (to be certain that you are looking at the right sttatement etc)

Answer (score 4):

the dichotomy... Are they non-overlapping? Only non-overlapping parts of a whole can make a dichotomy. As i see it:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException(new NullPointerException(NULL_ARGUMENT_IN_METHOD_BAD_BOY_BAD));
```

Comment: This would double the overhead for exception creation and wouldn't really help as catching `NullPointerException` would do nothing. The only thing which could help is `IllegalNullPointerArgumentException extends IllegalArgumentException, NullPointerException`, but we have no multiple inheritance.

Comment: I believe that more specific exceptions should be wrapped by more general exceptions. NPE is for an expression while IAE is for a method. Since methods contain statements that contain expressions, IAE is more general.

Comment: Regarding the overhead, I have no idea. But since the stacktraces would basically be identical except that the name of the exception changed in the middle, I think there shouldn't be too much overhead for double exceptions. If one is worried about the overhead, he can use "if" statements to return a null or -1 instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 4):

According to your scenario, `IllegalArgumentException` is the best pick, because `null` is not a valid value for your property.

Answer (score -1):

The definitions from the links to the two exceptions above are
IllegalArgumentException: Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument. 
NullPointerException: Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required.

The big difference here is the IllegalArgumentException is supposed to be used when checking that an argument to a method is valid. NullPointerException is supposed to be used whenever an object being "used" when it is null.

I hope that helps put the two in perspective.

Comment: The salient bit is that it is the *application* that is using null, not the runtime. So there is a fairly large overlap between "when a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument" and "when an application is using null". In theory, if an app passes a null for a field that requires non-null, both criteria are being met.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a "setter", or somewhere I'm getting a member to use later, I tend to use IllegalArgumentException.

If it's something I'm going to use (dereference) right now in the method, I throw a NullPointerException proactively. I like this better than letting the runtime do it, because I can provide a helpful message (seems like the runtime could do this too, but that's a rant for another day).

If I'm overriding a method, I use whatever the overridden method uses.

Answer (score -1):

You should throw an IllegalArgumentException, as it will make it obvious to the programmer that he has done something invalid.  Developers are so used to seeing NPE thrown by the VM, that any programmer would not immediately realize his error, and would start looking around randomly, or worse, blame your code for being 'buggy'.

Comment: Sorry, if a programmer looks around "randomly" upon getting any kind of exception... changing the name of an exception isn't going to help much.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, IllegalArgumentException conveys clear information to the user using your API that the " should not be null". As other forum users pointed out you could use NPE if you want to as long as you convey the right information to the user using your API.

GaryF and tweakt dropped "Effective Java" (which I swear by) references which recommends using NPE. And looking at how other good APIs are constructed is the best way to see how to construct your API.

Another good example is to look at the Spring APIs. For example, org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(Constructor ctor, Object[] args) has a Assert.notNull(ctor, "Constructor must not be null") line. org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Object object, String message) method checks to see if the argument (object) passed in is null and if it is it throws a new IllegalArgumentException(message) which is then caught in the org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(...) method.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally runtime exceptions should not be thrown. A checked exception(business exception) should be created for your scenario. Because if either of these exception is thrown and logged, it misguides the developer while going through the logs. Instead business exceptions do not create that panic and usually ignored while troubleshooting logs.

Answer (score -5):

If you choose to throw a NPE and you are using the argument in your method, it might be redundant and expensive to explicitly check for a null. I think the VM already does that for you.

Comment: The run time wont include a meaningful msg.

Comment: Actually this comment could derive some other opinion. Let the VM speak in `NPE` yet the programmers speak in `IAE` before the VM if they want to.

Comment: Expensive? I don't think that == null is that expensive... Beside, the null argument can be just stored for latter use, and will throw an exception long after the method call, making the error harder to track. Or you can create an expensive object before using the null argument, and so on. Early detection seems to be a good option.

Comment: down voting of this answer is misunderstanding of the hardware behind. Certainly the hardware checks (that CPU does) are cheaper that explicit checking. Dereferencing of null is a SegmentationFault (SegV) special case (access to a page not owned by the process) which CPU/OS checks and JRE handles as a special case throwing NullPointerException.