# Scala - Optional Arguments without requiring user to input Some(...)

Tags: scala, error-handling, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I am designing a program. I am new to Scala but it seems optional arguments are handled using the following:

```
def f1(my_string: Option[String] = None) = {

// Maybe do some pattern matching here to extract the value

}
```

However, for an end user this is pretty ugly as they will need to call this function like:

```
f1(Some("foo")
```

Is there a technique or pattern to turn this into:

```
f1("foo"))
```

and still work with an optional argument?i.e f1() also works?

The reason I ask is I have obviously used Scala libraries where adding an explicit Some(..) has not been necessary, but in their source code they have defined functions as above. I would personally use a default argument but wandering why this is a design pattern.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://users.scala-lang.org/t/passing-true-optional-arguments-to-functions/6087/3?u=balmungsan) as well as all the thread.

Comment: thanks that is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I'm puzzled by the asymmetric parentheses in the two uses of `f1` — typo?  (I know nothing of Scala, so it may be obvious to an aficionado.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Option` you could overload the method.

```
f1() :ReturnType = {...}

f1(arg:String) :ReturnType = {...}
```

Comment: Thanks @jwvh, just as a matter of interest, if I was working with a class instead, would the idiomatic way still be overloading the constructor?

Comment: In that case you probably want to use an **auxiliary constructor**. They have [some restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14210930/4993128) but can be useful.

Answer (score 4):

An option is to create a helper class *only* for such arguments to avoid the `anyToOption` implicit conversion in the linked thread:

```
class OptArg[A](val asOption: Option[A])

object OptArg {
  def NoArg[A] = new OptArg[A](None)
  implicit def fromValue[A](x: A): OptArg[A] = new OptArg(Some(x))
  // optional
  implicit def toOption[A](arg: OptArg[A]) = arg.asOption
}

// use
def f1(my_string: OptArg[String] = NoArg) = {
  // can use my_string as if it was Option,
  // or call my_string.asOption explicitly
}
```

In simple cases of course overloading will be more suitable, but not if you have many optional arguments.

The drawback is relying on implicit conversions, but I think this one is pretty benign and unlikely to trigger accidentally.

OTOH I think it's quite rare in practice that an argument is optional but "no argument" doesn't correspond to *some* default value of that type, so I'd look if it can be defined as

```
def f1(my_string: String = something)
```

to avoid the whole problem.

Answer (score 2):

Syntactic cost of `Option` in calls such as

```
f1(Some("foo"))
```

is trivial as compared to the value of minimised risk of null pointer exceptions in a large codebase. Hoare, a Turing Awardee, [appologised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Apologies_and_retractions)

> I call it my billion-dollar mistake. It was the invention of the null
>   reference in 1965.

Comment: But why compare it to that risk?