# java.bigDecimal divide in ruby environment

Tags: jruby, bigdecimal, divide

I right script in Ruby that include java classes

```
require 'java'
include_class 'java.math.BigDecimal'
include_class 'java.math.RoundingMode'
```

during the script I need to divide 2 java.bigDecimal

```
 one = BigDecimal.new("1")
 number1 = BigDecimal.new("3")
 number1 = one.divide(number1,RoundingMode.new(HALF_EVEN))
```

since I don't have intellisense in this IDE I'm not sure the syntax is right and the runtime error is:

uninitialized constant::HALF_EVEN

1. do I combine java object in the ruby scrpit in the right way?
2. how should I divide two java.bigDecimal object in ruby env?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
number1 = one.divide(number1, RoundingMode::Half_EVEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would've been `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN` in Java; it's  `RoundingMode::HALF_EVEN` in Ruby. You may also be able to use the `int` constants overload (i.e. [`BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_EVEN`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_EVEN)), but the `enum` overload is definitely the way to go.

You can control the *scale* of the quotient using the [`divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode mode)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal,%20int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29) overload.

Here's a Java snippet:

```
    BigDecimal one = BigDecimal.ONE;
    BigDecimal three = BigDecimal.valueOf(3);

    System.out.println(one.divide(three, 10, RoundingMode.DOWN));
    // prints "0.3333333333"

    System.out.println(one.divide(three, 10, RoundingMode.UP));
    // prints "0.3333333334"

    System.out.println(one.divide(three, 333, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY));
    // throws java.lang.ArithmeticException: Rounding necessary
```

#### Related questions

- [`ArithmeticException` thrown during `BigDecimal.divide`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749375/arithmeticexception-thrown-during-bigdecimal-divide)

  - `BigDecimal` can not represent `1/3` exactly (because it has a non-terminating decimal expansion)

#### API links

- [`java.math.RoundingMode`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)
- [`java.math.BigDecimal`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

  > A `BigDecimal` consists of an arbitrary precision integer unscaled value and a 32-bit integer *scale*. If zero or positive, the scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. If negative, the unscaled value of the number is multiplied by ten to the power of the negation of the scale.

Comment: In Ruby, to access static / class constants the notation is '::'. And JRuby automatically transalate the Java syntax to Ruby syntax accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! it works. a small follow up question - now when I divide 1/3 it returns 0 or 1 (according to rounding defined). is there a way that I can tune the accurate fraction, for example 1/3 = 0.3333 or 5/7=0.7142

Comment: @Eyal: use the `scale` parameter. See added examples.