# Dividing BigDecimals results in ArithmeticException

Tags: java, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ArithmeticException thrown during BigDecimal.divide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749375/arithmeticexception-thrown-during-bigdecimal-divide)

This results in ArithmeticException: http://ideone.com/RXeZw

Providing a scale and rounding mode will give me the wrong result. This example should output 50.03%. How to round this correctly?

For easier reference, this is the code:

```
BigDecimal priceDiff = BigDecimal.ONE
     .subtract(new BigDecimal(9.99)
     .divide(new BigDecimal(19.99)))
     .multiply(new BigDecimal(100));
System.out.println(priceDiff.toPlainString());
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal divisor)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) throws an ArithmeticException if the result cannot be exactly represented.
You will have to use provide a MathContext or a RoundingMode telling how you want to handle this. For example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        BigDecimal priceDiff = BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(new BigDecimal("9.99").divide(new BigDecimal("19.99"), MathContext.DECIMAL128))
                                             .multiply(new BigDecimal(100));
        System.out.println(priceDiff.toPlainString());
    }
}
```

works and prints

```
50.0250125062531265632816408204102100
```

Also, note the use of the [`BigDecimal(String)` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) to avoid problems when you create `BigDecimal` using a `double` literal.

Comment: Note that `RoundingMode` trims to integer precision, loosing decimals.

Answer (score 4):

You should use a MathContext as your division as an infinite number of decimals:

```
    BigDecimal priceDiff = BigDecimal.ONE
            .subtract(new BigDecimal(9.99)
            .divide(new BigDecimal(19.99), new MathContext(10, RoundingMode.UP)))
            .multiply(new BigDecimal(100));
    System.out.println(priceDiff.toPlainString());
```

However, that prints 50.025...

This would print 49.98:

```
BigDecimal priceDiff = new BigDecimal(9.99)
        .divide(new BigDecimal(19.99), new MathContext(10, RoundingMode.UP))
        .multiply(new BigDecimal(100), new MathContext(4, RoundingMode.UP));
System.out.println(priceDiff.toPlainString());
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

> In the case of divide, the exact quotient could have an infinitely long decimal expansion; for example, 1 divided by 3. If the quotient has a nonterminating decimal expansion and the operation is specified to return an exact result, an ArithmeticException is thrown.

The solution is to provide a `MathContext` to the division, for example `MathContext.DECIMAL128`. If you want rounding done the conventional way (rounding halves up rather than to the nearest even number), use `MathContext(int precision)`

You should also be creating your `BigDecimal`s with `String` arguments rather than `double` arguments, because the latter causes loss of precision.

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimal operations always tries to calculate exact result. Try this.

```
 BigDecimal priceDiff = BigDecimal.ONE
                .subtract(new BigDecimal(9.99)
                        .divide(new BigDecimal(19.99),RoundingMode.HALF_UP))
                .multiply(new BigDecimal(100));
        System.out.println(priceDiff.toPlainString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Keppil's answer

```
double d = (1 - 9.99 / 19.99) * 100;
System.out.printf("%.2f%%%n", d);
```

prints

```
50.03%
```

You are not going to get 49.98% as this is not the answer to your equation.

Comment: yes, i just got confused about all these numbers :-)

Comment: @dtrunk I find using `double` less confusing. ;)

Comment: I cannot use double as it would cause so many changes in the code

Comment: @dtrunk My opinion is that BigDecimal can cause as many bugs as it tries to solve as the code is much more cumbersome. Good luck. ;)