# Division between integers in Java

Tags: java, math, integer-division

I need to perform division between integers in Java, and the result should be a float.

Could I just use `/` symbol for it?  As in:

```
int integer1 = 1;
int integer2 = 2;
float quotient = integer1 / integer2; // Could I do this?
```

Comment: FYI: [Don't be surprised if the results seem wrong.](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: You might also want to check [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474535/best-way-to-represent-a-fraction-in-java) dealing with fractions. If you're going to use your division result in other calculations, you'll need all help you can get to minimize rounding errors.

Comment: I suggest you use `double` instead of `float` as `float` cannot represent all `int` values accurately. try `(double) integer1 / integer2`

Comment: @Peter: I agree. For the record, `double` is merely less bad than `float`. It doesn't solve the problem. I presume you already knew that, but I just wanted it to be on the record. :)

Comment: @Adam, 'double' can at least repesent all `int` values without error. It cannot represent all `int`/`int` values without error, but there is likely to be approriate rounding which is acceptible for the OPs applications.  Otherwise you need to use a Faction (for unlimited precision) or BigDecimal (for very long precision)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Cast one of the integers to float to ensure a floating point division:

```
float result = integer1 / (float) integer2
```