# Why doesn't this Java calculation return a floating point value?

Tags: java, floating-point

Just wanted to know

```
float percent = 1 + (25/100); // percent value is 1.0 and not 1.25
```

The result gives 1 but not 1.25

Thanks
Saikat

Comment: Integer division...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: division between integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203022/java-division-between-integers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because Java sees it like this:

```
(int) 1 + ( (int)25/ (int)100) = (int) 1
```

And then it's stored into a float. Try with `25.0` instead of `25`.

Answer (score 2):

you are doing an integer division. Let the compiler know that you are trying to do float division by explicilty making one of your operands a float literal. you can either make a float literal by appending F or f to the number or by appending .0 to the number.

```
25---> int literal
25.0---> float literal
25F----> float literal
25f----> float literal

float percent = 1 + (25F/100)
```