# how to write this type of fraction value as shown below?

Tags: java, android

[image]

Hot to write this type of fraction Value in java or android code as shown above ? Any idea/suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474535/best-way-to-represent-a-fraction-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean how to display it?
Unicode provides fractions up to eighths (used in finance)
http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/mathchart.html

On the other hand, if your output can render HTML, you can combine "sup" and "sub" tags

```
1 <sup><font size=-2>11</font></sup>/<sub><font size=-2>16</font></sub>
```

1 <sup>11</sup>/<sub>16</sub>

Comment: Right before the 11/16. I edited it and added it. It is put as normal character outside the sub or sup

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to create a sublcass the relativelayout and add 3 textviews for each number and the '/' as an image.

Another method would be to create a custom view and use the canvas to the draw the fraction.