# What is the correct way to represent and manipulate probabilities and percents in Java?

Tags: java

When calculating and manipulating probabilities in Java, and then expressing them as percentages, what is the best data structure to use to represent them?

The native `double` and `float` don't seem like particularly ideal candidates, since they have odd rounding issues which can introduce errors when the rounding happens multiple times and gets compounded.

`BigInteger` works well for calculating permutations and combinations, and `BigDecimal` seems like it might be a good candidate for the non-integer values, but is there something more suited to dealing with percentages already?

Note: In this case, the probabilities being calculated are similar in nature to those involving decks of cards, but with hundreds of cards. For the more math-inclined, I'm specifically working with [Multivariate Hypergeometric_distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: Are they always going to be integer percentages?  If so, use an int.  BigInteger is overkill because your number isn't going to be any bigger than what can fit in a normal integer.

Comment: No, the percentages will usually be in the range of [0,1], but will be displayed int a format like `23.29945%`. `BigInteger` is used for factorial calculations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to probabilities, I would suspect you would benefit from working with fractions.

Have a look at this question:

- [Best way to represent a fraction in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474535/best-way-to-represent-a-fraction-in-java)

Otherwise I think `BigDecimal` is your best choice. Beware however of the `java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion;`

Comment: Keeping things as fractions until the last minute (and then switch to a percent) seems like it might be a good idea. +1

Comment: You won't have any rounding issues at least :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do with a double, I think that using a double would be the best for getting a good value with percent...

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
//instance variable:
private static NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

//inside any method or event:
myAprValue = userInput / 100; 
percent = new DecimalFormat("0.0#%"); 

String st = percent.format(myAprValue);
```