# how do i take a measurement like 5' 3"1/2 and then multiply it by 1.414 and display answer in same format on android java

Tags: java, android, fractions

what I'm doing is this, I leave the 5' alone then I turn 3" into a decimal of a foot by dividing by 12 then I divide the numerator by the denominator then I add it all up and multiply by 1.414 it works but I dont know how I would display the foot inches and fraction of a inch

```
    c2c_fdecimal = f_num / f_den;
    c2c_fdeci_fft = c2c_fdecimal / 12.0;
    deci_of_foot = inchs / 12.0;
    total_travel= feet + c2c_fdeci_fft + deci_of_foot;

    toff_ftodeci = tkoff_numa / tkoff_dena;
    tkoff_inch = tkoff_inch / 12.0;
    sub_toff = toff_ftodeci / 12.0 + tkoff_inch;
    ans = (total_travel * ffformula) - sub_toff;
    //print out measurement format
    ansint = (int)ans;
    strip_inches = (int) ((ans - ansint) * 12.0); 
    //print answer
    editText2.setText(ansint + " ft" + strip_inches + " in");
```

Comment: ... and that, children, is why the rest of the world (except US and UK) has gone metric... ;-)

Comment: @aamos - ermm ... the UK went metric many years ago.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrication_in_the_United_Kingdom#Current_usage  Now admittedly a lot of people didn't like it ... but you can't please everyone.

Comment: The US also went metric in 1975

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd figure out the feet and inches in Java:

```
double resultInInches; // you start with inches...
int feet = (int)(resultInInches / 12);
double rest = (resultInInches / 12) - feet;
int wholeInches = (int)rest;
rest = rest-wholeInches; // rest now holds the fraction of the inch, eg 0.4141
```

Now all that's left to do is display `rest` as a fraction. I'm not familiar with what is or is not permitted in the Android SDK, and there's a bunch of ways to do this (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474535/best-way-to-represent-a-fraction-in-java)).