# Maths calculation in java Fraction

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a basic calculation. The program take in 2 numbers, it works fine with 10 divided by 5 and give answer 2. If any smaller value divided by a larger value it will give me 0, can I have the answer in fraction?

Example 8 divided by 100 equal 8/100 rather than 0.

```
 public class numtheory {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         int n1;
         int n2;
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );
         System.out.println("input number 1: ");
         n1 = scan.nextInt();
         System.out.println("input number 2: ");
         n2 = scan.nextInt();
         int temp1 = n1 / n2;
         System.out.print("\n Output :\n");
         System.out.print(temp1);
         System.exit(0);

     }

 }
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474535/best-way-to-represent-a-fraction-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert your numbers to `double`:

```
double temp = ((double) n1) / n2;
```

Comment: This gives him the result as a decimal, he wants to output as fraction.

Comment: Not sure of that: if he wants to output the fraction, he better not compute any calculation and output n1 + "/" + n2. And I don't think that's the question...

Comment: @newbieprogrammer you just have `int` and `double` (and others) primitive types to represent numbers. If you want/need a fraction interpretation of a `double`, you will need to implement it by yourself or use a third party library but since you're in learning phase you just have to stick to `double`.

Comment: i have search though the forum but none show how to output as fraction =(

Comment: @Vakh Judging from the OPs comments he does want to output as a fraction. Perhaps you could edit your answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to produce a fraction, you can just print out:

```
System.out.println(n1 + "/" + n2);
```

This will print out whatever numbers you're given though, they won't be reduced.
You can reduce them yourself however with something like:

```
int n = n1;
int d = n2;

while (d != 0) {
    int t = d;
    d = n % d;
    n = t;
}

int gcd = n;

n1 /= gcd;
n2 /= gcd;
```

And then print them out:

```
System.out.println(n1 + "/" + n2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using integers, you need to use double.
This because an integer can only contain while numbers where double can contain decimal numbers.

u could change all the int to double or cast the in to double by dooing

```
((double) yourIntValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also get the input as a string, and parse it with

```
double dval=Double.parseDouble(value);
```