# For loop, dividing one

Tags: java, for-loop, division

I have tried this in Javascript and have gotten my answers, but the answer I need must be more exact. I am trying to divide 1 by every number between 2 and 1000, and simply print them.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    for (int i=2;i<=1000;i++){
        double g = (1/i);
        System.out.println(g); // print "1/1,2,3,4.....1000" 
    }
}
```

I haven't done Java in a while, so I forget my correct variable names.

Answer (score 4):

Since both `1` and `i` are integers, integer division is being used. Either `1` or `i` need to be double in the `1/i` section of your code so that integer division is not used. You can do something like `1.0/i` or `1/((double) i)` to ensure that float division is used instead.

Answer (score 2):

replace `1` by `1.0D` that will result into `double`

Comment: The `D` suffix is optional for a `double`.

Comment: just to make it readable

Comment: I need it to be more exact than that, but at least a number is coming up now. Thanks.

Comment: if you need more precise answer go for `BigDecimal`

Comment: @user2962770 or you can use [`BigFraction`](http://www.vacant-nebula.com/code/BigFraction.java.source) (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474535/best-way-to-represent-a-fraction-in-java/474612#474612)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void main ( String args[] )  {

            for (int i=2;i<=1000;i++){
                double g = (1.0/i);
                System.out.println("1/"+ig); 
            }
```

**output**:
0.5
0.3333333333333333
0.25
0.2
0.16666666666666666
0.14285714285714285
0.125
.
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (note you can have as many digits of precision as you like) utilizing [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  java.math.BigDecimal ONE = java.math.BigDecimal.ONE;
  // 50 digits of precision.
  java.math.MathContext mc = new java.math.MathContext(50);

  for (int i = 2; i <= 1000; i++) {
    java.math.BigDecimal divisor = new java.math.BigDecimal(i);
    java.math.BigDecimal result = ONE.divide(divisor, mc);
    result.round(mc);
    System.out.printf("%d/%d = %s\n", 1, i,
        result.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: BigDecimal was the variable I was looking for, http://ideone.com/7FBtUL I tried on IDEone, and it didn't work...

Comment: It's `java.math.BigDecimal` and `java.math.MathContext`.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I copied and pasted ... not sure why it didn't pick those up.

Comment: You also missed `printf` instead of `println`. http://ideone.com/QJZRtY