# Calculations without loss of precision

Tags: java, numbers, calculator

I have

```
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(7);
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(13);
    BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal(26);
    System.out.print((a.divide(b)).multiply(c));
```

this code generates an exception:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
```

It means that I need to set `RoundingMode`.

But I need to get result only without loss of precision.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Seems like you want to work with fractions, not with decimals.  You could look around for a library with a Fraction class, or write your own.

Comment: Check this out: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fraction.html

There's also a discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474535/best-way-to-represent-a-fraction-in-java

Comment: @David Wallace thanks - you are right

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as `7/13` goes on to infinity what you're asking for is not possible. Your only possible option is to have a large precision when you divide.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing 7 by 13 will giving you long and non terminating decimal(**0.538461**53846.....). So you need to set the precision limit to it. Try this:

```
a.divide(b, x, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).multiply(c)
```

where x is the precision limit you want to set.

The [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) says:

> When a MathContext object is supplied with a precision setting of 0
>   (for example, MathContext.UNLIMITED), arithmetic operations are exact,
>   as are the arithmetic methods which take no MathContext object. (This
>   is the only behavior that was supported in releases prior to 5.)
>
> As a corollary of computing the exact result, the rounding mode
>   setting of a MathContext object with a precision setting of 0 is not
>   used and thus irrelevant. In the case of divide, the exact quotient
>   could have an infinitely long decimal expansion; for example, 1
>   divided by 3.

Comment: That will solve the exception, but the questioner needs the number to a high  precision, this defeats the objective.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal places of 7/3 is going to infinity. You must round it AFAIK. You can keep 6 decimal places because first 6 places repeats infinitely

http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%2F13

Answer (score 0):

Apache commons library can it

[Fractions](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fraction.html)