# Using irrational numbers. Return 1/22140 . Simplify?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Is this not possible? Should the fraction be simplified to avoid 'non terminating decimal expansion'
public class method {

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("1");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal ("22140");
BigDecimal c;


void cal () {
    
    System.out.println(c=a.divide(b));
    
}
```

Comment: It is not possible.  It can't be simplified.  `BigDecimal` has no way to precisely represent a *non terminating decimal expansion*.  And said expansion is a consequence of the maths.  If you want a precise representation of that number, you need to use a different number system (i.e. class) that precisely represents all integer fractions.  There isn't a standard class for this.

Comment: Besides `1/22140` is rational.

Comment: Thanks and yes I just checked, the (approx) value is 0.0000451671183378500451671183378500451671183378500451671183378500

Comment: Take your fraction and reduce it to lowest terms. If the denominator is not a power of 2, 5, or 10 then it cannot be represented exactly in decimal.

Comment: Maybe you find something here: [Best way to represent a fraction in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/474535/12323248)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input, I've managed a walk around of the problem by rounding of the fraction, taking lower and upper bounds into account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are asking if it is possible to represent 1 / 22140 exactly as a `BigDecimal`.  The answer to that is No.  The `BigDecimal` class cannot represent values with a non-terminating decimal expansion, and there is no simplification of the equation that will allow it.

Q: Why?

A: Basically, mathematics.  1 / 22140 cannot be represented as m * 10<sup>s</sup> where m and s are finite integers.

---

There are two practical alternative approaches:

1. You can use a `MathContext` argument when you do the division to specify how to round the number and how much precision to keep; e.g.

   ```
   c = a.divide(b, new MathContext(100, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
   ```

   This will compute the result with 100 decimal digits of precision, rounding (in the conventional way) to the nearest representable value.

   Note that this approach gives you *inexact* results; e.g. (1 / 3) * 3 won't be exactly 1, no matter what you set the precision to in the `MathContext`.
2. You can find and use a 3rd-party `Rational` or `Fraction` class, or write your own.

   Note that Java SE doesn't provide such a class.

Comment: I hate those users that write quality answers.

Comment: :-) (It's an "in joke" .... @aran has "hate issues" :-)  )

Comment: working it with my therapist. I think we are making huge progress. I am starting to hate him thou.