# Check if an array of objects with a specific property - java

Tags: java

I have an array list full of objects, i want to check if there are any objects with the name property equal to "maths".

How can this be done?

```
if(courses.contains(students.get(i).chosenPathway)){
```

Right now im using this but it doesnt work as courses is an array list of objects

Answer (score 2):

You should add more information next time about the name of the variables but i think i can get what u mean.
You need to check each object attribute from the list and compare it with equals for example like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < courses.size(); i++) {
if (courses.get(i).chosenPathway().equalsIgnoreCase("maths")) {
System.out.println("An object contains maths as chosen pathway.");
break;
}

}
```

Comment: Don't forget to up vote @guynumerouno :D

Comment: Better you use `equalsIgnoreCase` to match in a case-insensitive way.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array and then follow your logic. I assume that `Course` contains a list named `students`, from which you need to know if their `chosenPathWay` is "maths".

**`yourArray`** is the array that holds all Courses.

```
List<Student> matchingStudents=new ArrayList<Student>();

for (int i=0;i<yourArray.length();i++)
{
   Course c = yourArray[i];
   for (Student student: c.students)
      if (student.chosenPathway.equalsIgnoreCase(requiredPath)) //requiredPath = "maths"
          matchingStudents.add(student);

}
```

The code above assumes you must store all students that match the criteria. If you only need to know wether a Course has an student whose path is maths, just:

```
List<Course> matchingCourses =new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0;i<yourArray.length();i++)
{
   Course c = yourArray[i];
   for (Student student: c.students)
      if (student.chosenPathway.equalsIgnoreCase(requiredPath)) //requiredPath="maths"
      {   
         matchingCourses.add(c);
         break;                  //finish looping through this course
       }
 }
```

Comment: aran - Good answer. A couple of points: (1) In the second solution, you do not need a `List`, a `String` variable will be sufficient to store the first matching value. (2) You can also add a solution using the `Stream` API.

Comment: You are right about the second list being unnecesary. But about your 2nd point, i just hate Streams ; ) It's a personal thing

Comment: aran - Ha ha ...`Stream` is not so bad :)

Comment: Really, I do hate it. Working it with my therapist. Ask @Stephen C, he knows  --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/65164081/2148953

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have a list as below

```
List<Student> studentsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Prior to Java-8

```
for(Student stud : StudentList){
   if("maths".equals(stud.getChosenPathway())){
    //your logic goes here
    }
}
```

With Java-8 and above

to fetch single object

```
Optional<Student> stud = studentList.stream().findFirst().filter(s -> s.getChosenPathway().equals("maths"));
```

get all the objects

```
List<Student> empl = studentsList.stream().filter(s -> s.getName().equals("maths")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: the correct way would be this:
Optional<Student> stud = studentList.stream().filter(s -> s.getChosenPathway().equals("maths")).findFirst();
why did you put findFirst() in the first place ? that way you filter only find one element