# correct approach for design methods?

Tags: java, methods

I want to write a class method that returns a value, if the class method has an exception then it will be returned. I'm confused how to decide the class structure for this situation. What I am thinking about is that method returning an Object, if the method executes successfully then it returns a value otherwise an Exception message.

```
class ABC
{
   public Object xxx(int a,int b)
   {
      Object returnValue=null;
      try{retunValue=a/b;}
      catch(Excetion e){returnValue=e;}            

    return returnValue;
   }

}
```

Is it the correct way, I was also thinking about `setXXX` and `getXXX` methods, but this will not help me for this situation. Please help me, what is the correct approach to follow.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you returning exception? Instead throw the exception to the upper level routines .

Comment: Handle the exception or passed it for the next level. Don't combine both

Comment: @vrbilgi:i want to send exception message to root not exception object.exception catch it on same class where exception raises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can throw an exception in catch block when any exception is there. and catch the exception from where you are calling that method

```
class ABC {

    public static Object xxx(int a, int b) throws Exception{
        Object returnValue = null;
        returnValue = a / b;
        return returnValue;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        try {
            xxx(1, 2);
        } catch(Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would get an arithmetic exception for the above code . You should not throw an Arithmetic Exception, instead throw IllegalArgumentException by checking :-

```
public int xxx(int a,int b)
```

{

```
     if(b==0)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument divisor is 0");
    else
         return a/b;
```

}

See this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657887/how-should-i-throw-a-divide-by-zero-exception-in-java-without-actually-dividing)  for details .