# JAVA - Dividing by Zero & Returning a Correct Answer = Undefined

Tags: java

How do I make it so when wholenumber2 = zero it will display a different message then if wholenumber is < or > but not = zero it will display another message? I'm trying to prevent the basic error of diving by 0.

```
package SumDifProPACKAGE;     // Assigns package code.
import java.util.Scanner;     // Program uses class Scanner.
public class SumDifProCLASS { // Public class.
    public static void main( String[] args ){
      // Displays Welcome, information on calculations & creators name.
        System.out.printf( "%s\n%s\n%s\n",
         "--Welcome to JAVA Calculator!--", " --Sum, Difference, Product--", "  --??--");
        // Creates a Scanner to obtain input from the command window.
       Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        // Listed integers:
        int wholenumber1; // First whole number input.
        int wholenumber2; // Second whole number input.
        int sum;          // Sum of First & Second whole number input.
        int difference;   // Difference of First & Second whole number input.
        int product;      // Product of First & Second whole number input.
        int quotient;     // Quotient of First & Second whole number input.
        int remainder;    // Remainder of the Quotient.
        int zero = 0;
        // Requests input for First whole number.
        System.out.print( "Please enter first whole number..." );
        wholenumber1 = input.nextInt();
        // Requests input for Second whole number.
        System.out.print( "Please enter first whole number..." );
        wholenumber2 = input.nextInt();
        // Displays the sum of First & Second input.
        sum = wholenumber1 + wholenumber2;
        System.out.printf( "Sum        = %d\n", sum);
        // Displays the difference of First & Second input.
        difference = wholenumber1 - wholenumber2;
        System.out.printf( "Difference = %d\n", difference);
        // Displays the product of the First & Second input.
        product = wholenumber1 * wholenumber2;
        System.out.printf( "Product    = %d\n", product);
        // Displays the quotient without the remainder of the First & Second input.   
        quotient = wholenumber1 / wholenumber2;
        System.out.printf( "Quotient   = %d", quotient);
       // Displays the remainder, continuation of quotient.
        remainder = wholenumber1 % wholenumber2;
        System.out.printf( "r%d\n", remainder);
    }
```

Comment: Use if statement to check whether `wholenumber2 == 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way would be an if statement.

```
// Displays the quotient without the remainder of the First & Second input.   
if(wholenumber2 != 0){
    quotient = wholenumber1 / wholenumber2;
    System.out.printf( "Quotient   = %d", quotient);
}
else{
     System.out.printf("Cannot divide by zero");
}
```

btw: as a comment to some of the other answers, You should refrain form using exceptions to control execution flow.

Comment: This worked perfectly. This is only my second day in class programming in JAVA, no experince. I understand what you did here now. I should be able to use these lines in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `try catch` to handle (divide by zero) `ArithmeticException` or you can check if `wholenumber2` is zero or not

```
if(wholenumber2==0){
    // handle the case
} else{
    // handle the else case
}
```

check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657887/how-should-i-throw-a-divide-by-zero-exception-in-java-without-actually-dividing) as well it suggest number of ways to handle this situation

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make it so when wholenumber2 = zero it will display a different message then if wholenumber is < or > but not = zero it will display another message? I'm trying to prevent the basic error of diving by 0.

A simple If check you need  here.

```
if (wholenumber2  != 0) {
    // calculate   
}else{
  //show error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Division of an integer by zero gives[ArithmeticException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html).So You can catch it and display the message you want.

```
try{
     quotient = wholenumber1 / wholenumber2;
     System.out.printf( "Quotient   = %d", quotient);
}catch(ArithmeticException ae){
     System.out.print( "Result is Undefined");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition while requesting an input ->

```
int wholenumber2 = 0
while (wholenumber2 < 1) {
    System.out.print( "Please enter second whole number..." );
    wholenumber2 = input.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: This will help you validate the input and prevent such situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Long division_operation (Long a, Long b) throws Exception
{
    Long t = new Long (1);

    try
    {
        t = (a.longValue() / b.longValue());
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException e)
    {
        t = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        return t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that you are doing all the operations at once, I
suggest you check the value of wholenumber2 as soon as it is entered
i.e,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int wholenumber2 = input.nextInt();

while(wholenumber2==0)
{
System.out.println( "Whole Number cannot be zero!!" ); 
System.out.print( "Please enter Second whole number..." );
wholenumber2 = input.nextInt();
}
```