# Why does dividing by zero result in 9.223372E+18?

Tags: java, android, double

I'm making an Android calculator and I get 9.223372E+18 when I divide by zero. why wouldn't it show NaN or crash? I think that it results in 9.223372E+18 because that's the largest possible double value, since I'm dividing by zero and using a double data type. Since it will confuse the user, how do I get around this?

---

### Respond to Comments

Hi guys, thanks for all your responses. I appreciate it. I posted my code below.

```
public class CFM extends ActionBarActivity {
Double cfm, ac, volume;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cfm);

            EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            t1.setEnabled(false);
            t1.setFocusable(false);

            e1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                              int count, int after) {
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int before, int count) {
                    EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    volume = Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());
                    cfm = Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());
                    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                    ac = cfm * 60 / volume;
                    t1.setText(Double.toString((double) Math.round(ac * 100) / 100));
                }
            });


            e2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                              int count, int after) {
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int before, int count) {
                    EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    volume = Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());
                    cfm = Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());
                    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                    ac = cfm * 60 / volume;
                    t1.setText(Double.toString((double) Math.round(ac * 100) / 100));
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: Please give example code that demonstrates this.

Comment: Perhaps you should check if the denominator is zero before dividing, and if so use your own NaN?

Comment: what about 9.223372E+17 ? do you mean a problem just by that number or general problem by dividing by zero?

Comment: 9.223372E+18 isn't even close to the largest possible finite `double` value (which is ~1.8E+308). It is, however, the largest `long` value. I think there's something else going on in your code. Can you post a simple (hopefully just a few lines long), complete program that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 5):

`9223372036854775807` (roughly `9.223372E+18`) is the largest possible `long` value. The only way I can see this coming from dividing by zero is if you have a variable of type `long`. For example, the following code prints `9223372036854775807`.

```
long a = 1;
a /= 0.0; 
System.out.println(a);
```

When you divide a `long` by a `double`, the `long` is converted to a `double` first and the result is a `double`. Any positive `double` divided by `0.0` gives `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`, so `1/0.0` is `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`. Since `a` has type `long`, this is converted back to a `long`, giving the largest possible `long` value.

However, we would need to see your code to understand why you have variables of type `long`.

**Edit**

Having seen your code, I now realise that the problem is not a variable of type `long` but your use of `Math.round`. This is defined as follows:

> Returns the closest long to the argument, with ties rounding up.

`Math.round` therefore rounds `Double.PositiveInfinity` down to `9223372036854775807`. A better approach to displaying the result to 2 decimal places would be something like this.

```
String result = Double.isInfinite(ac) || Double.isNaN(ac) ? "Error"
            : new BigDecimal(ac).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toString();
t1.setText(result);
```

This will print `"Error"` if the user tries to divide by zero.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation pbabcdefp. I've added my code in the original comment. I believe that I declared my three variables as double, but I'm not a 100% sure. Is it because I'm using TextView for the answer?

Answer (score 0):

When calculating your value, use a detection mechanism to look for that number and show an error of 'cannot divide by zero'.

Either that or see if there is an exception handler that handles division by zero. Check here for an example of what exception to throw:

[How should I throw a divide by zero exception in Java without actually dividing by zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657887/how-should-i-throw-a-divide-by-zero-exception-in-java-without-actually-dividing)

or here: [Java division by zero doesnt throw an ArithmeticException - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137989/java-division-by-zero-doesnt-throw-an-arithmeticexception-why)

OR as deyur mentioned, yes you can always check if one of the arguments is zero and handle it that way.

If you are still having issues beyond this, share the core code snippets so we can help.

Comment: A more robust method would be to check the value of the divisor to ensure it's not zero before attempting the division.

Comment: @deyur Why bother? This is one of those scenarios, like with null checking, where it's better to just trigger the exception and catch it in the UI.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I'd rather my calculator tell me I can't divide by zero instead of crashing and leaving me wondering what happened

Comment: Thanks for sharing the websites MikeDub. I've added my code in the original comment.