# How to handle try/catch and throw with Junit test

Tags: java, exception, junit

Im kinda new to handling exceptions in Java with Junit, a little guidence would be much appreciated.

What I am trying to do:

- I surround the creation of the new CustomObject with a `try` as the user can pass in a `String` that will not match an `enum` when we call `valueof()`. I want to be able to catch an exception here, which I am, though I am told: "A catch statement that catches an exception only to rethrow it should be avoided.". There must be a better way to handle this?
- If the new object has the correct `enum` then I call `isValidObject`, which returns a `boolean`. If the `Integer` is not valid then I `throw` an exception.
- My test has a `@Test(expected = AssertionError.class)` and is passing.

Is there a better/cleaner way to use the exceptions?

I have the code below:

```
private CustomObject getObjectFromString(String objectDataString) {
        if (objectDataString != null) {
            String[] customObjectComponents = objectDataString.split(":");
            try {
                CustomObject singleObject = new CustomObject(EnumObjectType.valueOf(customObjectComponents [0]),
                        Integer.parseInt(customObjectComponents [1]));
                if (isValidCustomObject(singleObject)) {
                    return singleObject;
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown custom object type/value: " + EnumObjectType.valueOf(customObjectComponents [0]) + ":"
                            + Integer.parseInt(customObjectComponents [1]));
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                throw e;
            }

        }
```

Oh, and if anyone can recommend anything good to read about exception handling, that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A catch statement that catches an exception only to rethrow it should be avoided.". There must be a better way to handle this?

Yes, simply remove the try catch. Your code is equivalent to:

```
private CustomObject getObjectFromString(String objectDataString) {
    if (objectDataString != null) {
        String[] customObjectComponents = objectDataString.split(":");
        CustomObject singleObject = new CustomObject(EnumObjectType.valueOf(customObjectComponents[0]),
                Integer.parseInt(customObjectComponents[1]));
        if (isValidCustomObject(singleObject)) {
            return singleObject;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown custom object type/value: " + EnumObjectType.valueOf(customObjectComponents[0]) + ":"
                    + Integer.parseInt(customObjectComponents[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

That code will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the value passed to your `enum.valueOf()` is not valid or if your `isValidCustomObject` method returns false.

Note that it might also throw an `IndexOutOfBoundException` if the string does not contain a `:` which you probably want to test before calling `customObjectComponents[1]`. And it might throw NumberFormatException too.

And you seem to accept a null String as a valid entry, [which is probably not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java) (depends on your use case obviously).

I would probably have written it that way:

```
private CustomObject getObjectFromString(String objectDataString) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(objectDataString, "objectDataString should not be null");
    String[] customObjectComponents = objectDataString.split(":");
    if (customObjectComponents.length != 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Malformed string: " + objectDataString);
    }

    EnumObjectType type = EnumObjectType.valueOf(customObjectComponents[0]);
    try {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(customObjectComponents[1]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(customObjectComponents[1] + " is not an integer);
    }

    CustomObject singleObject = new CustomObject(type, value);
    if (isValidCustomObject(singleObject)) {
        return singleObject;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown custom object type/value: " + type + ":" + value);
    }
}
```

And finally, it would probably make sense for the CustomObject's constructor to check whether its arguments are ok or not by itself, instead of having to call a separate isValid method. The last block would then simply be:

```
    return new CustomObject(type, value);
```

which would throw an IllegalArgumentException from the constructor if required.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thankyou! Also the link about null handling is probably the most useful thing I have read in a long time.

Comment: You might like [this other link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter). I think the [third most voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8160/829571) makes most sense and is the standard way of handling null - [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8196334/829571) confirms it.