# Should a API throw NullPointerExceptions

Tags: java, api, exception

I use a commerical API and had a `NullpointException` coming from the API code.

The support tells me that it is expected because one of the input-parameters of the method I called was `null` and this parameter is needed to use the methdod.

Is this really my fault because I haven't checked the parameters before passing them to the API?

Isn't it bad practice to let `NullpointerExceptions` out of your API? If not I would have to check for all kind of `RuntimeExceptions` if I use a method of that API if I want to make sure my software doesn't crash.

If it is bad practice, are there any documents or specifications which refer to this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IllegalArgumentException or NullPointerException for a null parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter)

Comment: Let your software crash. Trying to carry on after all exceptions doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this really my fault because I haven't checked the parameters before passing them to the API?

Yes. The API defines the contract for how it can be used correctly. If a value is required and not passed in, I would fully expect a `RuntimeException` to come back. You should be doing validation on your data before you try to use the API to ensure you're giving it what's required. You should *not* be catching RuntimeException, as stonedsquirrel said.

Comment: I think not catching the Runntimeexception is the best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, I would say they should throw `IllegalArgumentException`

See: [IllegalArgumentException or NullPointerException for a null parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter)

And do read on, because this is the best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47710/2586804

The main difference is `IllegalArgumentException` makes it explicit that **you** have made a mistake when using the library.

Either way, you just need to use the library correctly. And only catch exceptions if you can handle them.

Answer (score 4):

You say that you would have to check for all `RuntimeExceptions`. The answer to that is no! It's OK for an API to throw unchecked runtime exceptions (regardless if it's a `NullPointerException`, a `IllegalArgumentException` or something else) in case it is used the wrong way.

In your case you use the API the wrong way, so you get a `NullPointerException`. If you want to catch that, how would your code look like?

```
try {
    useAPI();
} catch(NullPointerException e) {
    useAPIcorrectly();
}
```

Why not make that just `useAPIcorrectly();`? ;-)

You could put some debuging output in the catch block for development but the again: If in development, the stack trace of a `NullPointerException` is also sufficient for debugging. You would then fix it to the correct API use and never see those exceptions again :-)