# Making a parameter compulsory in Groovy

Tags: groovy

In groovy, it is possible to have a method as:

```
void myMethod(String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4)
```

Then invoke it with with param4 being null

```
myMethod(param1, param2, param3, null)
```

This means param4 is null.  Is there any way to make param4 compulsory and non - null?  So that you can *never* invoke it without specifying a value for it?

Comment: Tried it out but I don't see this behaviour: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/2035001

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always explicitly throw [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) when param4 is null or blank or whatever is your condition.

```
void myMethod(String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4) {
  if (!param4) throw new IllegalArgumentException("param4 is required blah blah!");
}
```

Or You can use @NotNull annotation.

Also Refer:

[IllegalArgumentException or NullPointerException for a null parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter)

[Which @NotNull Java annotation should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use)