# Check Map not to contain null keys and values

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, guava

For now I have this ugly code to check whether a hashmap contains null keys and values.
Is there ready to use Guava static method with same functionality?

```
    if (map != null) {
        // Check map does not contains null key
        try {
            if (map.containsKey(null)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("map contains null as key");
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            //It is ok. Map does not permit null key.
        }

        // Check map does not contains null key
        try {
            if (map.containsValue(null)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("map contains null price");
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            //It is ok. Map does not permit null value.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you're trying to do this?

Comment: Easy, efficient and elegant way to check whether a give map contains no null elements (keys and values)

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you're trying to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. There's

```
Preconditions.checkNotNull
```

which you should probably use. Surprisingly, it's faster than your simple check (it's optimized for better inlining of the common case, i.e., not throwing). It throws [NPE instead of IAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter).

There are also `MapConstraint`s, which AFAIK would allow you to create such a Map.

And there are also many classes not allowing `null`s, e.g., `ImmutableMap`. In theory you could do

```
ImmutableMap.copyOf(map)
```

but this would needlessly create a copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an ImmutableMap from the beginning, perhaps via its Builder, you'd get an error as soon as you tried to insert a null key or value. So that might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple enough:

```
public static <K,V>boolean containsNullKeysOrValues(Map<K,V> map){
    return containsNullKeys(map)|| containsNullValues(map);
}
public static <K, V> boolean containsNullKeys(Map<K, V> map) {
    return Iterables.tryFind(map.keySet(), Predicates.isNull()).isPresent();
}
public static <K, V> boolean containsNullValues(Map<K, V> map) {
    return Iterables.tryFind(map.values(), Predicates.isNull()).isPresent();
}
```

Pro: You don't have to catch any NPEs.

Con: In the worst case you have to iterate the entire map. Twice.