# Check method parameter for null or not?

Tags: java, design-patterns, methods, null

I have a method which doesn't allow null as parameter. Should i check the parameter inside the method for null and throw a IllegalArgumentException?
If yes, i would have to implement that check inside a lot of methods and it would look ugly.
So what is the best way?

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think there is a way a out from this. You should either check while calling the method or inside the method itself.

Comment: Project Lombok has an [`@NotNull`](http://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull.html) annotation for this purpose on constructors. On methods, you could use something like Guava's [`Preconditions.checkNotNull`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull(T)). This could be easily emulated.

Answer (score 7):

Well, that’s a question of personal preference.  I’d say:  Yes, you should.  It is a lot easier to debug if you throw an exception once you notice that there is a problem instead of getting an exception when you first access the object, maybe in an other method thousands of lines away.  (But throw a `NullPointerException` instead of `IllegalArgumentException`.)

But you have to do this check manually.  Of course, you can write a helper method or use Guava’s [`Preconditions`](https://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html):

```
public void test(final String string) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(string); // will throw a NullPointerException if string is null
}
```

*Edit*:  Especially if you write an API to be used by others, it is helpful to tell the people whether you are expecting non-null values or whether null is okay.  You can do so using the `@Nullable`, `@Nonnull` (both per variable or field), `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault` and `@ParametersAreNullableByDefault` annotations (both per class, package or method) located in `javax.annotation` (not part of the JDK).

*Edit 2*:  Okay, so why do I recommend to use a NPE instead of an IAE?  First of all, it’s the standard way to handle this problem.  The JDK does this, important libraries like Guava do this, and the one and only book about Java, *Effective Java*, recommends it (item 60).  But I know, this is not a valid argument.  In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter/47710#47710) mentioned by @fabian, @Jason Cohen argues in favor of a IAE.  His arguments are:

- *Documentation/definition of the exceptions.*  Yes, there is a list of applicable cases.  But the JavaDoc also states that it is not overall.  In fact, it states that ‘Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of the null object.’  That’s exactly what we do here.
- *Expectation of the stack trace reader.*  Firstly, I doubt that his assumption is true.  If I see an IAE, I think of an illegal *value*.  If I see a NPE, the problem is clear: `null`.  Secondly, I don’t think that these expectations are a valid argument here.  If everyone throws NPEs on `null` arguments, these expectations would change.  And the fact that many people misunderstand a behaviour does not mean that it this behaviour wrong.
- *IAE being more appropriate.*  That’s a personal question.  As said above, I think that the NPE is more appropriate as it indicates a `null` value.  Since NPE is clearly designed to handle `null` values, why would you chose an IAE instead?  ;)
- *No difference between `null` and illegal values.*  There *is* a difference.  To be honest:  I do not like this.  I really appreciate Ceylon’s approach of `null` being the only instance of the `Null` class.  (In my Java code, I usually use Guava’s `Optional` class to represent nullable variables.)  But the Java authors made a clear decision:  `null` is a very special thing, different from all other values.  This is the reason why it should be handled differently – e. g. with a different exception.  An IAE indicates that there is something wrong with a value:  maybe too short, too long, negative, positive, zero.  A NPE indicates that there simply is no value.

An other reason why I prefer the NPE is consistent behaviour.  From the caller’s point of view – assuming that I do not know the method implementation – I have to assume that calling a method with a `null` argument will cause a NPE once this argument is accessed.  Throwing a NPE on manual checking does not change this behaviour.  It just improves the moment the exceptions is raised.

Furthermore, using NPEs allows me to omit the manual check in very simple methods, e. g.:

```
public void test(@Nonnull final String string) {
    string.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please tell us a bit more about your choice of exception type. If you look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/47710/2991525) it seems that `IllegalArgumentException` should be prefered (and it would be my choice btw)

Comment: @fabian I did not know that there are people favoring an `IllegalArgumentException`.  I actually came from reading *Effective Java* that recommends an NPE (item 60), and I saw that many major libraries (as Guava) use NPEs too.  After reading the answer you mentioned, I still favor NPEs, but the comment field is to short to explain. ;)  I’ll add some words on this topic to my answer.

Comment: @fabian okay, I wrote a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late for the party but Java 1.7 added [`Objects#requireNonNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)).

It's just a simple method which will throw a `NullPointerException` if the parameter is null. I personally like this much better than failing inside the logic itself, since the method not only fails fast but one doesn't need to guess in a multiple varibales-statement which of the variables was null.

The method returns the non-null value which is helpful for Setters and Constructors:

```
public Repot(Date reportDate, String message) {
    this.reportDate = Objects.requireNonNul(reportDate);
    this.message = Objects.requireNonNul(message);
}
```