# If a char array is an Object in Java, why does printing it not display its hash code?

Tags: java, arrays, char

Printing a char array does not display a hash code:

```
class IntChararrayTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int intArray[] = {0,1,2};
        char charArray[] = {'a','b','c'};
        System.out.println(intArray);
        System.out.println(charArray);
    }
}
```

output :

```
[I@19e0bfd
abc
```

Why is the integer array printed as a hashcode and not the char array?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833562/static-char-and-int-array-difference

Comment: Another example to ilustrate the previous answers: `System.out.println((Object)charArray);`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all, a char array is an Object in Java just like any other type of array. It is just printed differently.

`PrintStream` (which is the type of the `System.out` instance) has a special version of `println` for character arrays - `public void println(char x[])` - so it doesn't have to call `toString` for that array. It eventually calls `public void write(char cbuf[], int off, int len)`, which writes the characters of the array to the output stream.

That's why calling println for a `char[]` behaves differently than calling it for other types of arrays. For other array types, the `public void println(Object x)` overload is chosen, which calls `String.valueOf(x)`, which calls `x.toString()`, which returns something like `[I@19e0bfd` for int arrays.

Comment: `System.out` is `PrintStream` (I wish it was PrintWriter, but due to consistency with older versions this type wasn't changed to writer).

Answer (score 4):

The int array is an array of integers where as the char array of **printable** characters. The printwriter has the capability to print character arrays as this is how it prints string anyway. The printwriter will therefore print them like a string, without calling the toString() method to convert it to a string. Converting an int array to a string returns a hash code, explaining why you get that output.

Take this for example:

```
int[] ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
char[] chars = new char[] { '1', '2', '3' }
```

If you were to print both those sequences using the method you used, it would print the hash code of the int array followed by '123'.

Answer (score 3):

System.out is PrintStream which has a special method for char[] arg

```
public void println(char x[]) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

int[] is printed via this method

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete. What does the `print(x)` method do?

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse arrays **are** objects in Java. No matter what type of array it is. It is always an object in Java.

But as far as your question is concerned, there is a method, `println(char[] array)`, in `java.io.PrintStream` class that prints out all characters from a `char array`. And that is the reason, when you pass a `char[]` as a parameter to `println()`, it doesn't call the `toString()` method of the `java.util.Array` class, but rather loops through the array and prints every character.

## Citation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char[])

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` actually gives you an Object of `PrintStream`. and its `println(params)` has some overloaded methods which are implemented differently for different type of `params`.

This `params` if being a `char[]` provides the output as `char[]` elements like `System.out.println(charArray);` outputs `abc` but not the hashcode as in the case of `int[]` like `System.out.println(intArray);` outputs `[I@19e0bfd`.

PS :- All the `array` are treated as `Object` in Java.

See the [Official Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char[]))

Moreover, for printing `array`, always use the `Arrays` utility class. Its method `Arrays.toString()` should be preferably used for printing `array` objects.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers correctly explain your case of a separate call to `PrintStream.println` and the same is true for `.print`. However your title could cover **other ways of printing**. `PrintWriter.println` and `.print` AND `.write` do have `char[]` overloads for a simple call.

However, formatting does not have a special case:

```
 System.out.format ("%s%n", charArray); // or printf
 myPrintWriter.format ("%s%n", charArray); // or printf
```

each outputs `[C@hash`, similar to the handing of `int` and other type arrays.

Nor does concatenation, often used in printing:

```
 System.out.println ("the value of charArray is " + charArray);
```

outputs `the value of charArray is [C@hash`.