# Why only println method is overloaded for character array but not for other arrays such as String,Integer etc?

Tags: java

*Why println method has a different overloaded method only for character array but not for other arrays such as String,Integer etc?*

For example

```
int intArray[] = {0,1,2};
char charArray[] = {'a','b','c'};
System.out.println(intArray);
System.out.println(charArray);
```

Output:

```
[I@19e0bfd
abc
```

Comment: most likely because those who implemented it chose it that way. In the end, were they supposed to create an overloaded method for each type that would ever come into existence?

Comment: Because a String represents an array of characters (and not an array of any other type)?

Comment: I am expecting answer from you all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a char array is an Object in Java, why does printing it not display its hash code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31218498) (EDIT: oh, you saw that already)

Comment: I know the answer for the above question as there are overloaded methods of println in PrintStream class. My question  is not the same. Why they didn't overload this method for other primitive types arrays or is there any reason behind overloading the character array method.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because it was designed all around **writing to character streams**.

`System.out` is a `PrintStream` which delegate writes to a `BufferedWriter` which in turn is instance of `Writer`.

some `Writer` possibilities

```
void    write(char[] cbuf)
abstract void   write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) 
void    write(int c)
void    write(String str) 
void    write(String str, int off, int len)
```

Because of that mostly every `void print(..)` method in `PrintStream` uses `String.valueOf()` to be able to pass it over to `writer` and say `writer.write(s)`

This was noticed and proposed to implement `toString` in arrays
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4168079, but obviously it was too late, due to compatibility/stability concerns. So the decision was to Implement helper methods to accomplish the same thing.

So now you may find a lot of
`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new int[]{1,2,3}))`

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` is a [`PrintStream (link)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) so it has several methods like :

- [`public void println(Object obj) (link)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-) used for `int[]` which is an object. It's used everytime your call it wih an object, and if `toString()` is not overloaded it'll print its "adress"
- [`public void println(char\[\] s) (link)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-char:A-) used for `char[]`

Because you cannot overload a method for *each* type of object in Java, the choice has been to do only this one

Answer (score 0):

Seems like designers decided it because in their opinion it would be the most used way of printing array containing `char`s. Note that if you want to print contents of an array instead of printing its address in memory, you can use method `toString()` provided in `Arrays` class. It lets you print contents of an array in a convenient way when array contains other types of objects than `char`. You call it this way:

`Arrays.toString(yourArray);`

Another way to print contents of array is creating a loop iterating over elements of array:

```
for (YourClass object : yourArray) {
    System.out.println(object);
}
```