# Java/Guava: handle 'null' arguments. Which exception?

Tags: java, guava

It's confusing: We all know the words from Doug Lea: "Null sucks". He is right.

Now I there are some approaches to throw exceptions by using googles guava. But what would be the right way now?

1) throwing an **NullPointerException**

```
private void foo(Object arg) {
  Preconditions.checkNotNull(arg, "arg 'null' not accepted");
}
```

2) or an **IllegalArgumentException**

```
private void foo(Object arg) {
  Preconditions.checkArgument(arg!=null, "arg 'null' not accepted");
}
```

3) or a **VerifyException**

```
private void foo(Object arg) {
  Verify.verify(arg!=null, "arg 'null' not accepted");
}
```

I mean, isn't the first approach obsolete cause we don't have a NullPointer access at this time?
And why this new third approach.

Could someone lift the fog?

Comment: Depending on the analysis, from time to time, null is a valid response. If it is not, try and figure out whether it was an error in the business logic, or the technical background that caused the null.

Comment: Update to Java8 and return `Optional<T>`

Comment: Check out the [docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Verify.html#verifyNotNull(T)) for guidance on the same. They can be used interchangeably for most situations.

Comment: I agree that Optional is good approach, but sometimes you need to throw excpetion (Transaction rollback, etc.). As you checking argument, I will go with IllegalArgumentException. You can have many cases when argument is illegal, NULL is one of them. (i.e. NULL, below zero, is even, etc. )

Comment: possible duplicate of [IllegalArgumentException or NullPointerException for a null parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter)

Comment: The built in Java libraries come down pretty firmly on the side of throwing NPE.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Optional<T> is also part of guava by the way. And this is a proper way to signal that 'null' is a valid input (or return value). I'm going to use it in the future and skip preconditions assuming that 'null' is never a valid input and should be checked by the calling function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no right way. Some people argue NPE since you passed a null pointer. Plus you can directly use `Preconditions.checkNotNull()` without any additional checks in code that you have to write (`!=null` is another 6-10 key presses, after all, plus people have to read more code to understand what you're doing).

`Preconditions.checkArgument()` makes more sense from an API point of view since the method doesn't want `null` arguments. Plus you have additional code to write and to read when you're debugging.

`Verifify` seems too weak for this for me, [after reading the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ConditionalFailuresExplained).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with `Aaron`. My two cents is that since in Java 7 [Objects.requireNonNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)) was added and it throws a `NullPointerException`, that is the way I go. To me it seems like the language developers have weighed in on this issue by doing so.

Answer (score 1):

"Effective Java" seems quite adamantly in favor of throwing a `NullPointerException` [IllegalArgumentException or NullPointerException for a null parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter/8160#8160)