# What is the best runtime exception to use when mandatory input is missing

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

I have service, a simple class that need to take input and run some business logic. Before executing this service, the user must set all the data. In general, it look like this:

```
public class TestService extends InnerServiceBase {

    /**
     * Mandatory input 
     */
    private  Object inputObj;

    @Override
    protected ErrorCode executeImpl() {
        //Some business logic on inputObj
        return null;
    }

    public void setInputObj(Object inputObj) {
        this.inputObj = inputObj;
    }
}
```

What is the best runtime exception to throw in case the `inputObj` is null ?

Comment: How about IllegalArgumentException

Comment: You might want to create a context specific custom exception and throw that

Comment: After answering, I realized... which method are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

`IllegalStateException` seems like the best fit.  The object is not in the correct state to have `executeImpl()` called on it.  Whatever exception you use, make sure the error message is helpful.

Whether you should be using an unchecked exception at all is a whole other question...

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the scenario.

- If this is part of an API that another developer is using, throwing `NullPointerException` is reasonable since you don't want that input to be `null`.  Adding a descriptive exception message would be helpful.
- If you're not interested in throwing an NPE, or this is part of code that's not going into an API, then you could throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, as `null` could be considered an illegal argument.

Answer (score 1):

If `setInputObj` is called with a `null` argument, and that's not valid, then throw `NullPointerException`. There's some debate over the "correct" exception here ([IllegalArgumentException or NullPointerException for a null parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter)), but Guava, Apache Commons Lang and even the JDK itself (`Objects.requireNonNull`) have settled on `NPE`.

If `executeImpl` is called before `inputObj` has been set, throw `IllegalStateException`.