# Java: BufferedWriter NullPointerException

Tags: java

I am attempting to write a method that has to take in a `Writer` object and use that to provide output to a file. The current code I have is throwing a `NullPointerException`, presumably because either there is an error in how I am creating my BufferedWriter or else in some instances `w` (the `Writer` object) is being passed as `null`. I have no control over what is passed as `w`, and cannot change the exceptions that this method is able to throw.

My code is as follows:

```
public void write(Writer w, Stat s) throws IOException {
    try{
        BufferedWriter writeFile = new BufferedWriter(w);
        writeFile.write(s.getData());
        writeFile.flush();
    } catch (IOException e){
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

(This assignment arises out of homework, but this question isn't the homework itself)

Comment: Have you initialized the `w` and `stat` variables? 
Does `stat.getData()` actually return data?
(I'm assuming `s` was supposed to be `stat` and you just typed it wrong in the question. Is that correct?)

Comment: Is there an error stacktrace?

Comment: Add null checks for both the writer and stat objects e. g. If(w ! =null & & s ! = null) after entering the try block

Comment: you should debug or add some print statement to see what the values of w, and s are. if these input parameters are null you cant do much about this. other than throw an exception

Comment: @Keith sorry, that was a type in creating the question. `stat.getData()` is actually `s.getData()` and yes, it does return data. `w` and `s` are provided in the method call.

Comment: @vikasn91 Thanks, I was racking my brain to think why `w` could be null, but it turns out that it was actually `s`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need both  `Writer w`and `Stat s` to be not null. Therefore you should reject them if they are null.

```
public void write(Writer w, Stat s) throws IOException {
   if (w == null)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("writer is null");
   if (s == null)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("stats is null");
   ...
```

Comment: You should add that although the `Stat` object may be constructed, its `getData()` may be returning `null`, too.

Comment: this is double exception checking, ie the NullPointerException is ALSO doing this check. Better IMO if you are going to go this route would be to put try {} catch {} blocks around the lines where you could get the nullpointerexceptions, catch the NPEs, and throw an IllegalArgumentException initialized with the NPE exception

Comment: @Keith I don't think that this belongs into the sanitizing of arguments. `writeFile.write(s.getData());`does not throw a NPE if `s.getData()` returns null.

Comment: Thanks for this, turns out that I was only thinking about the cases where `w` could be null, but it turns out the problem was being caused by `s`.

Comment: @DTR glad that you found it

Comment: @wero To be pedantic, why throw an `IllegalArgumentException` for a null variable? Effective Java, Item # 60 states to use IAE's for invalid _non-null_ parameters.

Comment: @Keith this would be worth an own question!  Some JDK code *indeed throws* a NPE if a required argument is null. On the other hand a NPE is *almost always* a sign that someone *forgot* to sanitize a argument. So seeing a NPE you simply don't know if it was a bug or a deliberate refusal. Using a `IllegalArgumentException` does not have this indecisiveness. Conclusion: I would change the recommendation of Effective Java#60.

Comment: And it is its own [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter) (with a _lot_ of opinions on the matter) :)

Comment: @Keith interesting. And the accepted (=official) answer deviates from the high-score (=best practice) answer :-)

Comment: @wero FYI -- `BufferedWriter.write(...)` **does** throw an NPE if `s.getData()` returns null