# How can I validate a copy constructor's parameter?

Tags: java, validation, parameters, null, copy-constructor

```
public class Rectangle {

  int width, height;

  public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }

  public Rectangle(Rectangle source) {
    this(source.width, source.height);
  } 
}
```

Let's say I have a class with multiple constructors, one of which is a copy-constructor (to copy an object).

Is there any way I can make check if source is null in the copy-constructor and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if it is? Because the other constructor call has to be the first statement in my constructor.

Comment: Why an `IllegalArgumentException` instead of just a `NullpointerException`?

Answer (score 3):

You could introduce a private static method that returns the relevant value with a `null` check to throw the `IllegalArgumentException` (in this case the width as it's the first parameter on the same object).

For example:

```
public class Rectangle {

    private int width, height;

    public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Rectangle(Rectangle rectangle) {
        this(getWidth(rectangle), rectangle.height);
    }

    private static int getWidth(Rectangle rectangle) {
        if (rectangle == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null value");
        }
        return rectangle.width;
    }

}
```

Reflecting on the comment to the question above, why not `NullPointerException`?

This question: [IllegalArgumentException or NullPointerException for a null parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter) has some good discussion points. But I'm inclined to agree with the sentiments of "Effective Java" that `NullPointerException` should be preferred as cited in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8160/7001059) to that very question.

> "Arguably, all erroneous method invocations boil down to an illegal
>   argument or illegal state, but other exceptions are standardly used
>   for certain kinds of illegal arguments and states. If a caller passes
>   null in some parameter for which null values are prohibited,
>   convention dictates that NullPointerException be thrown rather than
>   IllegalArgumentException."

Comment: That's redundant. If `rectangle` passes the first `getWidth` call, there is no need to check it again when getting the height.

Comment: @Holger very true, I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use java.lang.Objects for this, but it will throw NullPointerException (with a message your supply) instead of IllegalArgumentException:

```
    public class Rectangle {

    private int width, height;

    public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Rectangle(Rectangle rectangle) {
        this(Objects.requiresNotNull(rectangle, "rectangle was null").getWidth(), getHeight(rectangle));
    }
    ...
    }
```

You can also make width and height final if you want to.

Comment: Note that `getWidth()` returns a `double` (unlike accessing the field `width`) and there is no match for  `getHeight(rectangle)` in your code. And it's `java.util.Objects` not `java.lang.Objects`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this method somewhere in your codebase:

```
public static <T, R> R getIfNotNull(T instance, Function<T, R> extractor) {
    if (instance == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return extractor.apply(instance);
}
```

You could use it to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` from within your constructor:

```
public class Rectangle {

    int width, height;

    public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Rectangle(Rectangle source) {
        this(getIfNotNull(source, s -> s.width), source.height);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: all this would be needed just to throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, which is less idiomatic than a `NullPointerException`. In general, it's considered good practice to throw a `NullPointerException` if some non-nullable argument is `null`. And your original code was already doing this when attempting to dereference the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest workaround is not to have your constructor call another constructor.  There's no advantage to it, unless you're doing a classroom assignment where you're told you have to do it:

```
public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public Rectangle(Rectangle rectangle) {
    if (rectangle == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(...);
    }
    this.width = rectangle.width;
    this.height = rectangle.height;
}
```

Of course you now have duplicated code, but it's simple to extract that into a new private method used by both constructors.

This seems more straightforward to me than inventing a way to shoehorn a null check into the `this(...)`, as a couple other answers are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

If you're open to alternatives to a copy constructor, a static *copy factory* would buy you more flexibility:

> [...] you are usually better off providing an alternative means [to `Cloneable`] of object copying. **A better approach to object copying is to provide a copy constructor or copy factory.** A copy constructor is simply a constructor that takes a single argument whose type is the class containing the constructor [...]

(source: Josh Bloch's *Effective Java*, 3nd ed., item 13, p65)

```
public final class Rectangle {

  private final int width
  private final int height;

  public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }

  public static Rectangle newInstance(Rectangle source) {// <-- copy factory
    if (source == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("null source");
    }
    
    return new Rectangle(source.width, source.height);
  }

}
```

Arguably, throwing a `NullPointerException` would be more idiomatic than throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`, though.