# Should I write null checks for all of my methods?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, throw

I'm creating my own library like Apache Commons `DigestUtils` for learning purposes.

Inside of my `update()` method I've written a simple `if (something == null) throw new Exception` as `null` checking.

```
/**
 * Performs a digest update for the {@code String} (converted to bytes using the
 * UTF-8 standard charsets) with a specific {@code MessageDigest} and returns
 * the final digest data.
 *
 *
 * @param messageDigest the {@code MessageDigest} with a specific algorithm to
 *                      process the digest.
 *
 * @param data          the data to digest.
 *
 * @return the {@code MessageDigest} with the processed update for the digest.
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code messageDigest} is {@code null}.
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code data} is {@code null}.
 */
public static MessageDigest update(final MessageDigest messageDigest, final String data) {
    if (messageDigest == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("messageDigest cannot be null");
    if (data == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("data cannot be null");

    messageDigest.update(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    return messageDigest;
}
```

Now I'm not sure if I should write the same checks in other methods that must call the `update()` method, or only write it in the comments that the method throws the corresponding exceptions.

```
public static byte[] digest(final MessageDigest messageDigest, final byte[] data) {
    return update(messageDigest, data).digest();
}
```

or

```
public static byte[] digest(final MessageDigest messageDigest, final byte[] data) {
    if (messageDigest == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("messageDigest cannot be null");
    if (data == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("data cannot be null");

    return update(messageDigest, data).digest();
}
```

Note that `digest()` method calls `update()` method.

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*1.:* There is the function [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-), which is exactly for this purpose. It throws an exception if the given argument equals `null`.

```java
if (messageDigest == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("messageDigest cannot be null");
```

should be just

```java
Objects.requireNonNull(messageDigest, "messageDigest cannot be null");
```

*2.:* The best practice to throw an exception because of `null` is to throw it *where the `null` shouldn't occur in the first place*. This is the motivation behind the [*Fail Fast Principle*](https://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf).

When a `null` reference occurs where it should *not* be, you want to throw an exception, or handle it, at *exactly* that spot. You *don't* want to pass the `null` referece to other methods/functions. Otherwise you would have a harder time debugging your code when the passed `null` reference causes problems in your program. This is because it won't be clear where the `null` reference occured in the first place; but what actually *caused* it is what you want to fix/handle. An example:

```java
public class Demo {
    public void a(Object obj) {
        b(obj);
    }
    private void b(Object obj) {
        c(obj);
    }
    private void c(Object obj) {
        // Calculation using obj.
    }
}
```

If it's clear that `a` should never get a `null` reference passed, this is the correct place to check for it.

```java
public void a(Object obj) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(obj); // Throw exception when null.
    b(obj);
}
```

It's bad when you do a `null` check in every single method because the fact that `obj` shouldn't be `null` counts for all those methods, thus it's enough to place the `null` check where the `null` shouldn't occur in the first place, i.e. `a`. The program shall *fail fast*.

It would be even worse to put the `null` check in `c` because `c` should logically never receive a `null` reference from `b`, and `b` shouldn't receive one from `a`. If the `null` reference causes problems in `c`, you will have a harder time finding out if `null` occured in `b` or `a` or the code that called `a`. You *want* to know that because you want to fix the problem of the occuring `null` reference, *not* the problems caused by it. Of course, sometimes you can't fix the occurrence itself, but you can try to get as close as possible to the occurrence and reduce collateral "damage" done by it.

There is no real goto way to place `null` checks. You have to place them at the right places to make the program *fail fast* on occurring invalid objects. It's up to you to decide where the best places for `null` checks are because it all depends on the exact case.

I hope this gives you a good idea about how to approach this.

Comment: What do you think about the JavaDoc about this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter) @akuzminykh

Comment: @user11611653 It depends on the case. The `IllegalArgumentException` states that an argument is invalid. This involves all kinds of arguments, i.e. not just `null` references. You throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when a `String` has a wrong pattern, when an `int` is negative where it should be positiv and so on. The `NullPointerException` is caused by dereferencing a `null` reference, so it's about `null` and nothing else. If your code could throw an exception because of `null`, use `NullPointerException`, otherwise `IllegalArgumentException`. The *fail fast* principle is most important.

Answer (score 0):

The better thing to do is just let the `update()` method do it's thing, and if it throws an `Exception`, you throw an exception too. There are two common things to do, both throw the `Exception` that you get one too. One way to put a `throws SomeException` in the method name where `SomeException` is the `Exception` that you are excepting.

```
public static byte[] digest(final MessageDigest messageDigest, final byte[] data) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return update(messageDigest, data).digest();
}
```

So if you get an `Exception` from `update()`, it will automatically throw it. NOTE: you don't need to throw `IllegalArgumentException`'s because they are a type of  `RunTimeException`, which are automatically thrown. The second way is try catch, which gives you a little more options.

```
public static byte[] digest(final MessageDigest messageDigest, final byte[] data) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    try {
        return update(messageDigest, data).digest();
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // Do whatever you want. You can even throw e if you want.
    }
}
```

This allows you to do whatever you want if you find there was an exception.

Comment: I also have a method that calls the digest() method. For example, digestHex() calls digest(). And digest() calls update(). Should I use the same practice? @Higigig

Comment: Yes, you should. However, you don't need to do anything with `IllegalArgumentException` because as I stated before, it is a `RunTimeException` and automatically thrown.

Answer (score 0):

1. Starting with JDK15 (or is it in 14 already?), NPEs thrown by the system itself (i.e. when you run, say, `Object o = null; o.hashCode();` will have all the details; in particular the text of the expression. That means that if in your code an NPE would occur 'naturally' (because you dereference the variable, or pass it along to another method that always does that), there's no need for the null check. Stylistically the problem with that is if later you change your code so that it doesn't necessarily dereference, you lose the effect that invoking the method will a null argument throws. Something to keep in mind.
2. It is in my experience more common to explicitly throw 'NullPointerException', i.e. to write `if (param == null) throw new NullPointerException("param")`. The various libraries that automate throwing this also default to NPE as a rule.
3. You do not need to write the if. java core ships with a utility to one-liner it: `Objects.requireNonNull(param, "param");` is a lot shorter than your 3-line `if` block!
4. You can use [lombok's `@NonNull`](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull) to generate these null checks automatically, saves you even more typing.
5. You can configure your IDE to warn on changing parameter values; this means you no longer have to put the keyword 'final' 15,950,951 (approximation) times in your source files. Saves you *a lot* of typing.
6. Whilst the other answer in this question so far says that you don't *need* to declare `throws IllegalArgumentException`, which is true, doing it for documentation purposes is (again, my experience) common.
7. There are annotations to mark non-nullity. Aside from the lombok one, various libraries exist that give you compile-time null checking, and they generally are built into the major IDEs, or there's a plugin for them, so you get as-you-write errors that you're passing (potential) null values to methods that don't want it, or doing useless null checks (null checks on for example values returned from methods that indicate they never return null). If you can rely on all the users of a library to use such tools, you don't need the runtime nullchecks at all, but I would suggest you keep them; you can't rely on your users to have these tools, I think. Nevertheless, consider annotating your params so that those who do get the benefit of the compile-time checks.

For the compile-time annotations, you have a wide array of choices here (unfortunately): There's [checkerframework](https://checkerframework.org/) which is by far the most expansive, letting you go a lot further than compile-time null check guards. There's also the baked-into-your-IDE sets: [eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Null_Analysis)'s and [intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html)'s are the most common, but there are many more.

*Only* lombok's will generate a runtime nullcheck for you, and IDEs can be configured to consider it for compile-time analysis as well, giving you the best of both worlds. Alternatively, combine one of these framework's annotations with `Objects.requireNonNull`.

Comment: What do you think about the JavaDoc about this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/illegalargumentexception-or-nullpointerexception-for-a-null-parameter) @rzwitserloot

Comment: Given that Objects.requireNonNull throws NPE, and that (especially with JDK15+'s better NPE messages) lots of methods don't make it explicit and therefore throw the NPE inherently,  you CANNOT get around the fact that passing null to methods in places where you shouldn't do that _WILL_ definitely throw NPEs. So, lean into it: All code should throw this. It makes no sense to split the world in two on this, and IAE can be eliminated, whereas eliminating NPE seems undoable. Any further arguments boil down to stylistic choice, and those take a backseat to pragmatism, no?